# Salesforce OAUTH implementation

Tags: ios, salesforce, single-sign-on

I'm developing Salesforce iOS application.

From application frequently the user has to modify data which is available on Salesforce.com.

When user tap on edit I'm launching salesforce login screen and prompt to enter username and password all the time.

So I have decided to implement SSO using Salesforce Oauth. I have done everything I'm able to receive a access_token once user authenticate with Salesforce.com.

My question is lets say "If the user want to edit a lead with id as 0097hjy7" , URL to edit this lead will be "https://sales.mysalesforce.com/0097hjy7" when this URL launch on browser it prompt to enter username and password again.

How can I navigate the user to "https://sales.mysalesforce.com/0097hjy7" this URL without asking username and password all the time by using the access_token available with me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I resolved this issue by adding Salesforce iOS SDK to my project and using some classes like SFOauthCoordinator and SFOauthCredentials. At the end we need to prepare a frontDoorUrlWithReturnUrl which is available on "SFAuthenticationManager" class.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this issue by adding Salesforce iOS SDK to my project and using some classes like SFOauthCoordinator and SFOauthCredentials. At the end we need to prepare a frontDoorUrlWithReturnUrl which is available on "SFAuthenticationManager" class.